# is it required to use reducers for state in react

Tags: reactjs, reduce

I've read quite a bit about the need to use reducers (redux, useReducer, etc.) to manage state in react: they all insist that complex and scalable applications need them, but, remarkably, I haven't been able to find a concrete example, with source code, where you can observe the difference of behavior with and without reducers.

What I am looking for is an example with source code where it can be clearly seen that by not using reducers some error or unwanted behavior occurs and the corresponding fix.

Comment: [https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer](https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer)

Comment: What kind of "difference in behavior" are you looking for? The behavior should be the same--they don't address behavioral issues, they address development complexity.

Comment: @DaveNewton Something measurable. What I've found on the net are opinions which are largely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a concrete example. But from what I have read and have experienced first-hand, reducers allow you to '`[create small pools of data contexts][1]`'. This helps isolate state from one another and can prevent state from 'bleeding' into another and causing unpredictable side effects. Also keep in mind that all reducers should be pure functions meaning that one input should always have the same output. This also makes it easier when it to debugg.

take a look at this article:

[https://rajeshnaroth.medium.com/why-use-reducer-hooks-for-state-management-in-react-c9528f615ddf#:~:text=Reducers%20are%20handy%20for%20creating,your%20state%20where%20it%20belongs](https://rajeshnaroth.medium.com/why-use-reducer-hooks-for-state-management-in-react-c9528f615ddf#:%7E:text=Reducers%20are%20handy%20for%20creating,your%20state%20where%20it%20belongs).

Comment: thanks, gonna read it.